# Why this code moving my gameobject in such an odd way?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My Code

```
        Vector2 moveDirection;
        moveDirection = (Sensitive.transform.position - gameObject.transform.position).normalized;
        float deg = Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Atan(moveDirection.x / -moveDirection.y);
        if (moveDirection.y < 0) deg -= 180;
        Vector3 to = new Vector3(0, 0, deg);
        transform.eulerAngles = to;
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(moveDirection.x, moveDirection.y) * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

In the update function intended to look at and move to Sensitive, though it points correctly doesn't move correctly and I can figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`transform.Translate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) by default interprets the input as a local direction & distance. You're  providing the input in world direction & distance, so you should use the optional 2nd parameter and specify `Space.World`:

```
transform.Translate(new Vector3(moveDirection.x, moveDirection.y) 
    * (speed * Time.deltaTime), Space.World);
```